# searching for snippet that diagnose filesystem performance with dask

Tags: dask

I would like to diagnose the filesystem performance upon multiple accesses with dask.
Would anybody have a snippet to do that?

Context: working on an HPC platform, my sysadmin has required me to move to a new filesystem and I suspect its performance is quite poor.
My workflow involves distributed dask, netcdf and zarr file processing.

Answer (score 0):

I would use standard profiling techniques and look for file system operations like file.read or file.open.  The dask distributed profiler may be able to help here a little.